# Cannot Flush Permalinks with WP-CLI

Tags: wp-cli

I am using wp-cli to create a WordPress website. I am running LAMP server. I am able to change the permalinks from ugly to pretty with the following commands:

```
wp rewrite structure '/%postname%'
wp rewrite flush
```

However, when I visit the website and click on the post, the permalinks are changed but it gives 404 not found. Is there a way to refresh the permalinks without going to wp-dashboard and click "Save" on the permalinks?

Comment: I found out the problem was that .htaccess file was not regenerated. It can be done using the `wp rewrite flush --hard` command and setting `mod rewirte` in wp-cli config.yml.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding `wp rewrite flush --hard` command and setting `mod rewirte` in the global `wp-cli` configuration file:

```
wp rewrite structure '/%postname%/'
wp rewrite flush --hard
```

config.yml

```
apache_modules:
  - mod_rewrite
```

In  this way, the .htaccess file gets regenerated. According to the [official docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/rewrite/flush/), this is needed in order to flush the permalinks.

I also wrote a detailed guide on how to update the permalinks on Apache web server with wp-cli: [How to Update WordPress Permalinks with WP-CLI on LAMP Server](https://nasiothemes.com/how-to-update-wordpress-permalinks-with-wp-cli-on-lamp-server/)